# Maven- Deploy release version of jar

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I am new to maven and I'm using the maven release plugin to do a release and the maven deploy to deploy it. What I am noticing is that when I do 
`mvn release:prepare` it makes two commits, as it should be, with the first one being without the snapshot in the pom.xml and then a newer version in the pom.xml with the snapshot. However when I then do `mvn deploy` it deploys the snapshot jar to my internal repository. How will I get it to deploy the release version of my jar? Should I be checking out HEAD~1 and then do `mvn deploy`?

Comment: what do u mean by released version of your jar ?

Comment: I believe that he is using something like Git to track the code changes for the program.  A Git tag would then represent the version to be released.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly unclear, but the goal to run after `release:prepare` is `release:perform`.

Depending on what you're trying to do, the `install` or `deploy` plugins may also be useful.

Sonatype, the people that run Maven Central, have a very helpful guide to using the release plugin, as well as other ways of releasing:

http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html#performing-a-release-deployment-with-the-maven-release-plugin